# Цикл повторяющийся с фиксированным тикрейтом

Tags: java

```
int tickRate = 100;

for(;;){
//some code
Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Проблема заключаеться в том, что мне нужно выполнять код каждые 100 мс, но ждать нужно не 100 мс, а то, сколько осталось до следующего тика. Т.е. нужно сделать так, что бы поток спал 100 мс, но с учётом времени работы кода. Например, код проработал 5 мс, то спать нужно не 100 мс, а 95 мс.

Comment: Просто в цикле нужно создавать новый поток и запускать его.

Comment: Замеряйте время выполнения кода (напр., с помощью `System.nanoTime()`) и вычитайте его из 100 мс.

Comment: И не забудьте использовать GC без пауз, а то STW поломает все замеры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вам подойдет `ScheduledExecutorService`, который позволяет управлять временем запуска заданий.
В данном примере таск выводит в консоль текущее время в мс. Можно убедиться, что это происходит достаточно точно. Просто вставьте в тело таска свой `//some code` и настройте нужный временной интервал.

```
    // создаем таск
    Runnable runnableTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(new Date().getTime());
        }
    };
    // или даже так
    // Runnable runnableTask = () -> System.out.println(new Date().getTime());


    // исполняем его каждую секунду
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableTask, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```